# MediaElement.js setSrc() Loading The File But Not Changing pluginType

Tags: javascript, html5-video, mediaelement.js

I'm working on a page that uses [mediaelement.js](http://www.mediaelementjs.com/) to play mp3/mp4/wmv (yes, we have a lot of wmv).  I have a list of links and those links should change the player.  My effort is to make the changes to the player through javascript so that the page doesn't refresh.

This code is working, but it refreshes every time.  (link removed)

```
<?php
$file = null;
$file = $_GET["file"];
$format = null;
if (preg_match("/mp4/i", $file)) $format = "mp4";
if (preg_match("/webm/i", $file)) $format = "webm";
if (preg_match("/wmv/i", $file)) $format = "wmv";
if (preg_match("/mp3/i", $file)) $format = "mp3";
if (preg_match("/ogg/i", $file)) $format = "ogg";
$mime = null;
if ($format == "mp4") $mime = "video/mp4";
if ($format == "webm") $mime = "video/webm";
if ($format == "wmv") $mime = "video/wmv";
if ($format == "mp3") $mime = "audio/mp3";
if ($format == "ogg") $mime = "audio/ogg";
$element = "video";
if ($format == "mp3" || $format == "ogg") $element = "audio";
// you have to escape  (\) the escape (\) character (hehehe...)
$poster = "media\\120701Video.jpg";
$height = "360";
if ($format == "mp3") $height = "30";
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Embed</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="include/johndyer-mediaelement-b090320/build/mediaelementplayer.min.css">
<style>
audio {width:640px; height:30px;}
video {width:640px; height:360px;}
</style>
<script src="include/johndyer-mediaelement-b090320/build/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="include/johndyer-mediaelement-b090320/build/mediaelement-and-player.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li><a href="embed.php">Reset</a></li>
    <li><a href="?file=media/120701Video-AnyVideoConverter.mp4">Alternative (mp4)</a></li>
    <li><a href="?file=media/120701Video-Ffmpeg-Defaults.webm">Alternative (webm)</a></li>
    <li><a href="?file=media/AreYouHurting-Death.wmv">Alternative (wmv)</a><li>
    <li><a href="?file=media/AreYouHurting-Death.mp3">Alternative (mp3)</a></li>
</ul>
<?php if ($file) { ?>
<video src="<?php echo $file; ?>" controls poster="<?php echo $poster; ?>" width="640" height="360"></video>
<div id="type"></div>
<script>
var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
var player = new MediaElementPlayer(video, {
    success: function(player) {
        $('#type').html(player.pluginType);
    }
});
<?php } ?>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code requires `<video>` to be loaded, initially and with a file, so that the player mode (`pluginType`) is set.  It will, then, only play formats that the pre-established mode supports (firefox in native mode won't play mp4).  See a [live demo of the ajax version](http://www.flcbranson.org/embed.php?player=mediaelement).

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Embed</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.mediaelementjs.com/js/mejs-2.9.2/mediaelementplayer.min.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.mediaelementjs.com/js/mejs-2.9.2/mediaelement-and-player.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:player.pause(); player.setSrc('media/120701Video-AnyVideoConverter.mp4'); player.load(); player.play();">Alternative (mp4)</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:player.pause(); player.setSrc('media/120701Video-Ffmpeg-Defaults.webm'); player.load(); player.play();">Alternative (webm)</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:player.pause(); player.setSrc('media/AreYouHurting-Death.wmv'); player.load(); player.play();">Alternative (wmv)</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:player.pause(); player.setSrc('media/AreYouHurting-Death.mp3'); player.load(); player.play();">Alternative (mp3)</a></li>
</ul>
<video controls src="media/WordProductionCenter.mp4"></video>
<div id="type"></div>
<script>
var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
var player = new MediaElementPlayer(video, {
    success: function(player) {
        $('#type').html(player.pluginType);
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems like I need something like `setType()`, but I see no such option.  I've read a couple pages that referenced refreshing the DOM after the javascript runs, but I haven't been able to successfully do it (I know enough about javascript to hack things around and get stuff working, but not enough to create whole new things).

It is worth noting that Silverlight doesn't work with Internet Explorer 8 or Safari (not sure if it's my code, mejs, or the browsers).  Also, neither Silverlight nor Flash play mp3 or webm (again, not sure where the problem lies).

Is there a way to dynamically load different types of files into mediaelement?

Comment: Well, I've given up on this.  I just can't seem to get it to work the way I expect.  On to other projects...

Answer (score 9):

You can change the source of the MediaElement player using `setSrc` which also accepts an array of values.
For example:

```
player.setSrc([
   { src:'newfile.mp4', type:'video/mp4' },
   { src:'newfile.webm', type:'video/webm' }
]);
```

Comment: I did use .setSrc, but I didn't add the type.  I'll see if that changes anything.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!!! I was about to throw my Mac out the window, been hunting for this solution for hours.

Comment: So was I at the time!

Answer (score 1):

for me it work!!

```
    if (video == undefined)
        video = new MediaElementPlayer('#playerVideo');

    video.pause();
    video.setSrc($("#linkVideo").val());
    video.media.load();
    video.play();
```